# Why did Draco want to be friends with Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

Or think Harry would want to be friends with him? 'My name is Draco Malfoy. I am a racist, I despise gingers and mudbloods, I hate Gryffindor house, and my parents work for the man who killed your parents. Do you want to be my friend?'

I mean WHY Harry??

Comment: When Draco tried to befriend Harry, that was before Harry was sorted in Gryffindor, and before we knew Draco despised muggle-borns. It could have been nothing more than one 11 year old boy wanting to befriend a famous 11 year old boy.